# compare two lists in tcl and obtain list of only differences between lists

Tags: tcl

```
proc ListComp { List1 List2 } {
set DiffList {}
foreach Item $List1 {
  if { [ lsearch -exact $List2 $Item ] == -1 } {
     lappend DiffList $Item
  }
}
foreach Item $List2 {
  if { [ lsearch -exact $List1 $Item ] == -1 } {
     if { [ lsearch -exact $DiffList $Item ] == -1 } {
        lappend DiffList $Item
     }
  }
}
return $DiffList
}
set diff [Listcomp $list1 $list2]
puts diff
```

Input:

```
list1 {red, yellow, green, blue, orange}

list2 {red, green, blue, orange}
```

expected output: `yellow`

output received:

```
                 yellow green
                 green blue
                 blue orange
                 orange
```

The search and match should be either ways. if length of list1 > list2, the extra element in list1 should be printed. if length of list1 < list2, the omitted element in list1 should be printed

Comment: If you correct the bugs 'ListComp' vs 'Listcomp' and `puts $diff`, then it works for me.

Comment: Since Tcl 8.5, you can use the simpler `if {$Item ni $List2} ...` instead of lsearch.

Comment: `set a [list]       #list a is {red blue green}`

input:

`red  4   5   #to be removed`
`blue  5   1  #to be removed` 
`yellow 9   2    #not to be removed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, each list could have elements that the other does not. The best approach is therefore to compute two result lists at the same time, being the elements present in one list that are absent in the other and *vice versa*. Then it's up to you to decide what to do with the information.

```
proc ComputeUniques {listA listB} {
    set A {}
    set B {}
    foreach a $listA {
        dict set A $a 0; # The 0 is just an arbitrary value
    }
    foreach b $listB {
        dict set B $b 0
        dict unset A $b
    }
    foreach a $listA {
        dict unset B $a
    }
    return [list [dict keys $A] [dict keys $B]]
}
```

Note that `dict unset` does nothing if the key is absent, which is convenient, and the results are in the order of occurrence of the input keys (strictly in the order of first occurrence, in the case of input lists that are not set-like).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Also, can you suggest a way to delete a line from file if that line has the entries of string list $a ex: `set a [list]       #list is {red blue green}` input file has line: ```` `red  4   5   #to be removed` `blue  5   1  #to be removed` `yellow 9   2    #not to be removed` ````

Answer (score 2):

While your code (apart from typos) works, it can be done much simpler like this:

```
set diff [lmap n [concat $list1 $list2] {
    # Skip the elements that are in both lists
    if {$n in $list1 && $n in $list2} continue
    set n
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. sorry about typos. However, if the proc call is inside a foreach loop of file read line by line, I am not getting the desired output.
`foreach entry $lista  entry1 $listb {`
`set list1 [lindex $entry 2]`
`set list2 [lindex $entry 2]`
`set diff [Listcomp $list1 $list2]`
`}`

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are doing here. With this code your lists are created with the same command and so they will be the same. But if the result is not what you expect, your input is probably not what you think. I suggest to add some puts commands to check what they are.

Comment: looks like I was using proc call in an irrelevant foreach loop. The problem has been sorted. Thanks for the help. Also, can you suggest a way to delete a line from file if that line has the entries of string list `$a` 
ex: `set a [list]       #list is {red blue green}`
input file has line:
````
`red  4   5   #to be removed
blue  5   1  #to be removed
yellow 9   2    #not to be removed`
````

Comment: You can't delete lines from a file. You can copy data from one file to another, skipping the lines that you don't want. At the end move the new file on top of the original one. But that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use an array (or a dict):

```
set list1 {red yellow green blue orange}
set list2 {red green blue orange}

if {[llength $list1] > [llength $list2]} {
    set long $list1
    set short $list2
} else {
    set long $list2
    set short $list1
}

foreach elem $long {
    set diff($elem) 1
    # or: dict set diff $elem 1
}
foreach elem $short {
    unset -nocomplain diff($elem)
    # or: dict unset diff $elem
}

set difference [array names diff]
# or: set difference [dict keys $diff]
```