# Tcl lsearch between two lists for matches

Tags: list, match, tcl

I have two lists **a** and **b**. I want to search if each element of **b** matches with the elements of **a**, and those elements of **a** that are different to append in a new list.

```
set a {Gyr_prep.pdb Gyr_HECH_243_1_prep.pdb Gyr_DRG_prep.pdb Gyr_ATH10_prep.pdb}
set b {ATH10}

foreach i $a {
    if {[lsearch -glob $b *\[$i\]]==-1} {
        lappend diff $i
    }
}

puts $diff
```

The output is:

`Gyr_prep.pdb Gyr_HECH_243_1_prep.pdb Gyr_DRG_prep.pdb`

This code works if elements of **b** does not contain any **G** character or a same numeric character.

However if **b** list contains for instance **Gyr** or **DRG**, then the regexp is not working. It is also not working if **b** contains *HECH_243*_*1* element, thus giving as an output:

`Gyr_prep.pdb Gyr_DRG_prep.pdb`

instead of:

`Gyr_prep.pdb Gyr_DRG_prep.pdb Gyr_ATH10_prep.pdb`

Any idea what to use as a regexp for this specific case (an example below)?

```
set a {Gyr_prep.pdb Gyr_HECH_243_1_prep.pdb Gyr_DRG_prep.pdb Gyr_ATH10_prep.pdb}
set b {Gyr HECH_243_1 DRG}
```

expected output should be:

`Gyr_ATH10_prep.pdb`

```
set a {Gyr_prep.pdb Gyr_HECH_243_1_prep.pdb Gyr_DRG_prep.pdb Gyr_ATH10_prep.pdb}
set b {ATH10}

foreach i $a {
    if {[lsearch -glob $b *\[$i\]]==-1} {
        lappend diff $i
    }
}

puts $diff
```

Comment: Why are you using a `[]` character class in the pattern?

Comment: And why isn't your expected output in the second example an empty list? All elements of `a` have Gyr in them...

Comment: Comparing two lists has been repeatedly covered by previous questions. Have you searched for previous Q&A? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63034928/compare-two-lists-in-tcl-and-obtain-list-of-only-differences-between-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fully functional code for solving this particular problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set a {Gyr_prep.pdb Gyr_HECH_243_1_prep.pdb Gyr_DRG_prep.pdb Gyr_ATH10_prep.pdb}
set b {Gyr HECH_243_1}

proc listcomp {a b} {
foreach i $b {
      if {$i == "Gyr"} {
          set a [lsearch -inline -all -not -exact $a "Gyr_prep.pdb"]
          set b [lsearch -inline -all -not -exact $b "Gyr"]
      }
  }

  set diff $a

  foreach j $b {
      set diff [lsearch -all -inline -regexp -not $diff (?q)$j]
  }
return $diff
}

puts "[listcomp $a $b]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the full list $a, and remove the matching items for each of the terms in $b:

```
set a {Gyr_prep.pdb Gyr_HECH_243_1_prep.pdb Gyr_DRG_prep.pdb Gyr_ATH10_prep.pdb}
set b {HECH_243_1 DRG}

set diff $a
foreach str $b {
    set diff [lsearch -all -inline -regexp -not $diff (?q)$str]
}
puts $diff
```

The `(?q)` prefix for a -regexp matching style means that a literal match should be done. The difference with the -exact style is that the string is not anchored, so it may appear as part of the list elements.

Comment: A very good idea. This piece of code is actually working (at least partially solves the problem). I actually used it and fully solved the issue by introducing an "if" conditional for presence of "Gyr" in "b" list and removing "Gyr" and "Gyr_prep.pdb" elements from "b" and "a" list, respectively.

The fully functional code is available below as a separate post.

Thanks Schelte.

Answer (score 0):

Using a variable `$appn` to jump if any b elements matches with a element. then unmatched elements are appended to new list `$diff_ele`

```
set diff_ele {}
foreach a $list_a {
    set appn 0
   
    foreach b $b {
        if {[regexp .*$b.* $a match]} {
            set appn 1
            break
        }
    }
    if {$appn == 0} {
        lappend diff_ele $a
    }
}
```